# Ruby/Tk in a browser

Tags: ruby

Is there a quick and easy way to make a ruby/Tk script run in a browser? I wrote a handy-dandy little ruby/tk script to do stuff. A friend saw it and said that his friends would love to use it, but they are extremely non-technical and cannot handle installing ruby (even though I showed him how simple it is). What he wants is for me to give him a link that someone can click on a browser and magically make the tool run.

I've looked around and get the impression that it cannot be done. 'it just does not work that way'. But I have not seen a clear 'NO' . I see things on how to get ruby to run in a browser, but not the Tk part. I also looked at rubyscript2exe but get the impression that it was abandoned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't directly run Ruby in the browser like that.

There are websites such as RubyFiddle which let you run short snippets. What they're actually doing is executing the code remotely then displaying the result.

Because this code is actually being executed remotely, there's no way of running something interactive (like a TK UI) with it. There are some services which give you a hosted Ruby environment with working Terminal, but even these aren't going to work with a TK UI.

This section of Ruby Gems https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables has a good list of all the tools available to package Ruby apps for distribution though, so you might be able to send them a simple installer to allow them to use it locally?

I've had a lot of success doing this with https://github.com/larsch/ocra/ which is actively maintained.

Comment: Great! I'll go check those out! Thanks!